# Getting Information Title by ID in opencart

Tags: opencart

I searched for finding an example but was unsuccessful. 
I am new to Opencart and developing a theme for a customer. I installed information module for static texts. In some menus I need to get information title, description and link of those by ID. Normally putting the full link hardcoded is a way but if I'll use SEO tools in the future, all the links should be routed automatically. So I don't want to type URL hardcoded. It should refer to ID.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you new to Opencart or are you new to the developing as well? Do you understand the MVC? If you understand MVC, PHP and MySQL then take a look into `catalog/controller/information/information.php` and `/catalog/model/catalog/information.php`, you should be able to move on on your own then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking. The information module already generates SEO urls if they are enabled and being used.

To get the descriptions into the information navigation module, just open up the `catalog/controller/module/information.php` file and add them to the array that is sent to the template:

```
foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
    $this->data['informations'][] = array(
        'title' => $result['title'],
        'href' => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id']),
        'description' => $result['description']
    );
}
```

You can then access this in the module's template the same way as a title, e.g.

`<?php echo $information['description']; ?>`

If it isn't the information navigation module that you're working on, then you just need to copy-paste the code above into whichever controller you're working on, but add these two lines above it:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/information');
$this->data['informations'] = array();
```

Then in your view, use it exactly the same as the nav module:

```
<?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ....
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question since you are answering to not even asked problem...

Comment: You could be right, check my first paragraph... it's unclear, he speaks of the information module and wanting descriptions. Best let him decide :)

Comment: @rjdown thanks for the information. that's exactly what i am searching.